# Dealing with elements that are not visible due to zoom level

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We have automation processes that have been scraping a website for months. Recently we discovered that our scraper isn't working.

Turns out, the website has been changed so that they have a table with 9 columns placed inside a frame. However, either the frame or table is styled improperly and only the first 6 columns are on the screen at 100% zoom because the table is too big. When you zoom out to about 50%, the rest of the columns manage to fit in the view.

Unfortunately, there is a button on the very last column that I need to click, but Selenium doesn't like it and says the element is not in view at 100% zoom.

When I use the following to check whether it's in view or not

```
while (!elmt.isDisplayed()) {
  // wait for it
}
```

and manually zoom the page out so that the column with the button comes into view, it then successfully clicks the button.

How can I zoom the page out?

Comment: If the element is not in view and cannot be scrolled to, this is going to be a problem. WebDriver doesn't work well with zoom levels other than 100%, so I'm interested to hear from more experienced people on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I had the similar issue while testing in Safari.

The work around is to zoom out the page programmatically before you perform any operation on that page.

With help of js you can do this:

```
document.body.style.zoom = "30%"
```

Or whatever value is required. In selenium make use of javascript engine to execute this script.

This worked work around perfectly worked for me.

Comment: I will try this when I get a chance to and get back to you.

Comment: Using the idea of changing element properties on the fly, I looked more closely at the properties and noticed that there are several hardcoded widths here and there, which resulted in a frame that was only allowed to take up 470px (and the rest of the page was basically empty space). When I changed them to allow it to fill up 100% of the page, it looked fine. I'll go with changing some other properties now that I know I can do something like this!